# nginx keeps adding trailing slash

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

I want to create an alias to the "static" folder:

```
location ~ ^/myapp/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/ {
    alias /var/lib/myapp/$1/static/;
    autoindex on;
}
```

But, if I have the URL:

> https://mydomain/myapp/section1/page.html

I'm being redirected to:

> https://mydomain/myapp/section1/page.html/

which causes a 404.

If I access:

> https://mydomain/myapp/section1/

I can correctly see the list of all the html files (because of "autoindex on").

However, if I have this config:

```
location /myapp/ {
    alias /var/lib/myapp/;
    autoindex on;
}
```

nginx does NOT add the trailing slash, and therefore I can correctly access the .html pages. The problem with this config is that "static/" has to be included in the URL, such as:

> https://mydomain/myapp/section1/static/page.html

How can I make nginx NOT add a trailing slash in the first example above?

Answer (score 1):

An `alias` within a *regular expression* `location` block requires a value which specifies the full path to the target file. You need to capture the remainder of the URI in the `location` statement and append it to the end of the `alias` statement.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/myapp/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ {
    alias /var/lib/myapp/$1/static/$2;
    autoindex on;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried that before (and now again), but unfortunately that gives me 404 for every attempt, even with "autoindex on". I tried with and without the ".html" file in the URL.

Comment: Have you cleared the browser’s cache. Also, are there any other location blocks above this one?

Comment: DevTools open with "Disable Cache" enabled - any changes are immediate. The other location blocks are: "location = /", "location /" and "location /awstats/icon".